# Что значит запись вида const { name } = value?

Tags: javascript, const

Увидел в описании использования одного из npm-пакетов запись  вида `const { NAME } = value`. В JavaScript не профи, так что никак не могу понять/найти **зачем эти скобки вокруг имени переменной** и чем тогда это отличается от обычного `const NAME = value`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Это «сахар» для `const NAME = value.NAME;` Удобно, когда нужно присвоить несколько таких переменных

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это называется [деструктуризация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring), используется для более короткой записи

```
const {name} = value; // value = {name: ''}
name; // ''

// то же самое что и
const name = value.name;
```

Можно использовать в параметрах функции

```
const foo = ({prop}) => {}
foo({prop: 'prop'});
```

Для возвращения нескольких параметров из функции

```
const foo = () => ({var1: 1, var2: 2})
const {var1, var2} = foo();
```

**Важно**: имена переменных должны совпадать с ключами в объекте

```
const {name} = {prop: 1}; // name = undefined
// но если очень хочется:)
const {prop: name} = {prop: 1};
// name = 1
```

Так же работает с массивами

```
const [a, b] = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // a = 1, b = 2
```

Вот как теперь можно обменять значения двух переменных

```
let a = 1, b = 0;
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

Comment: По ссылке выше описана возможность менять имена переменных.  Думаю стоит добавить это в ответ