# Что означает запись, которая напоминает массив, но используется на месте имени константы

Tags: javascript

Доброе утро. Надо срочно разобраться в коде, а JavaScript только начинаю изучать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в следующем коде что такое `[value1, setValue1]`?

Напоминает массив, но используется на месте имени константы.

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState([
  { id: 1, text: "1" },
  { id: 2, text: "2" }
]);

const [value2, setValue2] = useState("");
```

Также, насколько я понимаю, `useState` - это функция, которая принимает массив из двух объектов, каждый из которых состоит из `id` и `text` (в первом выражении), правильно?

Подскажите пожалуйста по каким ключевым словам я смогу найти информацию, чтобы в этом разобраться, либо дайте ссылку.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это `react`? Ответ зависит от того, что возвращает функция `useState`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо что выслушали, благодаря этому разобралась - эта функция возвращает массив, для которого, как я понимаю, используется деконструирующее присваивание (ещё не проходила эту тему), и значениям value1, setValue1 присваивается первый и второй элемент соответственно. И да, в проекте действительно используется React.

Comment: @РустамГимранов Спасибо :)

Comment: Вы не правы! написал ответ ниже! Если это React, то это хук который полностью присваивает значение в useState первой переменной! и создаёт callback для изменения данного значения

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/873461/256824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам массив в `const` это [деструктурирующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: "1" },
    { id: 2, text: "2" }
]);
```

---

Я почему-то уверен что это `React.js` Уж очень это похоже на типовой пример хука `useState`.
Собственно если я прав, то происходит следующее. [Ссылочка на документацию](https://learn-reactjs.ru/core/hooks/state-hook)

`useState` помогает определить начальную переменную для состояния. В вашем примере в `value1` запишется МАССИВ полностью и далее создастся функция обновления данной переменной. То есть `setValue1([...])` эквивалентен `setState({value1 : [...]})`.
Единственный аргумент который передаётся в `useState()` это начальное состояние для первой переменной указанной в `const`.